# Ionic $cordovaDeviceOrientation.clearWatch() doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic, ngCordova app that creates a compass. It works fine but my call to clearWatch() doesn't do anything.

I have a template with two buttons:

```
<ion-view title="Compass Page">
    <ion-content>
        <button class="button" ng-click="startCompass()">Start</button>
        <button class="button" ng-click="stopCompass()">Stop</button><br>
        {{dir}}
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The controller is as follows:

```
angular.module('starter')
    .controller('CompassCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDeviceOrientation) {

        $scope.dir = 0;

        $scope.startCompass = function() {
            var options = {
                frequency: 500
            };

            $scope.watchId = $cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options)
                .then(
                    null, 
                    function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }, 
                    function(result) {
                        $scope.dir = result.trueHeading;
                    }
                );
        };

        $scope.stopCompass = function() {
            $cordovaDeviceOrientation.clearWatch($scope.watchId);
        };
    });
```

The compass starts fine when I press the start button and the {{dir}} value is updated as I rotate the device.  My call to clearWatch does nothing.

Any pointer as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Aidan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone could explain I'd be grateful but what I have found is that

```
$scope.watchId = $cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options).then(...);
```

is different to

```
$scope.watchId = $cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options);
```

Having looked at the source code for both the cordova plugin and ngCordova I have found that storing the promise from watchHeading and then adding the then() clause fixes the problem:

```
$scope.startCompass = function() {
    var options = {
        frequency: 500
    };

    $scope.watchPromise = $cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options);

    $scope.watchPromise.then(
            null, 
            function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }, 
            function(result) {
                $scope.dir = result.trueHeading;
            }
        );

};

$scope.stopCompass = function() {
    $cordovaDeviceOrientation.clearWatch($scope.watchPromise.watchID);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer but I had the same problem right now and I hope to be helpful.
I assume that's because in the first case

```
$scope.watchId = $cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options).then(customFunction);
```

$scope.watchId is taking the returned value of the customFunction and not the promise returned by the watchHeading
In the second case

```
$scope.watchId = $cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options);
```

$scope.watchId will be the returned promise of the watchHeading function.
So by executing the clearWatch in the first case you are trying to clear a possible returned value of a custom function (that can still be a interval but it's really uncommon) meanwhile in the second case you will clear the right object.
Anyway, I need to say that I'm not completely sure about it but I still hope to have been helpful

Davide